# using curl and json with express server

Tags: node.js, json, express, curl

I wanted to test some api on my local express server using curl and json formated datas, following curl documentation, like :

```
curl -v -k https://www.localhost.fr/api/test -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"test":"test"}'
```

No json parsed in express and exposed headers are wrong :

```
''Content-Type'
'application/json''
```

I removed quotes from Content-type, headers are correct but now express.json() middleware send an error :

Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

I tried to rewrite datas :

```
{"test":"test"}

{test:test}

"test"

"{\'test':\'test\'}"
```

..etc I think I tried all ways i could to write them..

only {} an "{}" don't throw parse error

I tried then to look at what express receive as datas using middleware raw(), on top of json's one, and I get nothing to parse, no body, no datas. (second issue/misunderstanding  here)

I specify everything works fine outside curl (react app using fetch).

curl 7.79.1, nodejs 16, express 4

Somebody ran into this issue? curl is a cool tool, but i'm really confused here.. ;(,  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows yes, it works! thank you ! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you must use double quotes: `curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"test\": \"test\"}" ...`